# How to handle Repeatable Read isolation level serialization exceptions in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions

The paragraph related to a Repeatable Read isolation level in the official PostgreSQL documentation says: "Applications using this level must be prepared to retry transactions due to serialization failures." I tried to simulate the failure using psql console and got "ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update", but I didn't find any information related to the actual Java exception being thrown, how to handle it in Spring (JdbcTemplate be more precise) in order to execute the transaction again with the updated row?